# Update value in controller when factory changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a factory service to control a shopping cart and I'm will problems to sync the data with controller when I'm still configurating the shopping cart.

the process consists of analyzing whether or not the user is logged. If he is **not**, then `spCart = 0`, if he is logged, then I'll have to make other verifications. Let's say I have 2 more verifications to do:

- If user has a valid address,
- If the address is within a range, so the shipping cost will be 0;

If user doesn't have valid address, then `spCart = 1`;

If he has an address and is whitin the range,

```
spCart = [
    'items':[], //add items here
    cost: '0'
];
```

Or if isn't in the range:

```
spCart = [
    'items':[], //add items here
    cost: '9.99'
];
```

The problem is, some of these verifications needs to wait for a `$http`, this way I'm not able to sync the `spCart` value from the factory, with the controller. This is what I did:

controller:

```
function CartController(factCart) {
    var sp = this;
    factCart.initialLoad();
    sp.cart = factCart.getCart();
};
```

factory:

```
function factCart (localStorageService,factMain) {
    var spCart = 0;


    var service = {
        initialLoad:    _initialLoad,
        getCart:        _getCart
    };
    return service;

    function _initialLoad() {
        var userData = localStorageService.cookie.get(ngApp);
        if (userData) {
            var func = 'load_address';
            factMain.methodGet(func).then(function(res){ //$http from main factory
                if(res==0) {
                    return spCart = [1];
                } else {
                    _checkRange(res);
                }
            });
        } else if (!userData) {
            return spCart;
        };
    };

    function _checkRange(data) {
        spCart = [];
        spCart['items'] = [];
        /*
         logic here
        */
        if (inRange) {
            spCart['costs'] = {
                cost: 0;
            };
            return spCart;
        } else {
            spCart['costs'] = {
                cost: 9.99;
            };
            return spCart;
        };
    };

    function _getCart() {
        return spCart;
    };
};
```

The problem is, the `spCart` value is always `0`, it doesn't change when I update it, and I don't know what I can do to solve this issue.

Note: I had this problem when adding items to the shopping cart, the view didn't updated. I solved that issue by using `$apply()`. But in this case, i couldn't use `$apply`, it said 'Cannot read property...'

Comment: Why not returning a promise in the controller and in the `then` block you can get your cart ?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but since there is a lot of verifications I need to do before getting the cart, I was doing it in the factory

Comment: In your code: `spCart = []; spCart['items'] = [];` Why are you creating an empty array and setting hash properties on the array?

Comment: Because there is other configurations values for the chekout. I'll have spCart['checkout'] with values such as user id, company id, name, date, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work. I don't know if it's the best solution, so I'll keep the question opened.

But I had to keep the initial array just like I want it to be when all the verifications are OK and added an extra field to control everything.

So I'll have an array like this:

```
spCart = [];
spCart['address'] = {
    verification: 0,
    address: 'name of address',
    //..etc..
};
spCart['items']= [];
//..Rest of array - for checkout only
```

This way the data inside the `verification` is being updated. It's not the best way (or at least not how i expected) because I'm exposing the whole array, instead of a single value.

So, if there is a better solution, it will be very welcome.